# How to start Firefox 3.5 in fullscreen mode?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, fullscreen

I want Firefox to start in fullscreen mode and can't find any trigger that makes it do this. 
Any tricks?

I'm running Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 4):

Install the [**AutoHide add-on**](http://www.krickelkrackel.de/autohide/), this will allow you to use the "-fullscreen" parameter on the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

check [Mouse runner's Firefox guide](http://www.mouserunner.com/FF_Tips_Full_Screen.html).

> [AutoHide](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6524) is a very easy to use and learn extension that will allow you
>   to view Firefox in true Full Screen mode with or without toolbars including the Windows Taskbar.
>
> You can also **set AutoHide to start Firefox in Full Screen mode** and
>   easily toggle between Full Screen and normal viewing by pressing F11.

[LifeHacker article](http://lifehacker.com/217327/download-of-the-day-autohide-firefox) reference.

---

Additionally, the [**Full Fullscreen** addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1568) also claims it -- have not checked that.

> supports full screen on browser start

Answer (score 0):

BTW OS X : CTRL + Mouse Down - Brings up contextural menu toggle option as F11 not valid

```
       ALSO - Not true fullscreen - check out "Plainview" browser for os x kiosk options
```